# So i'm currently learning javascript from codecademy.com , i have got a issue trying to solve a code about control flow

Tags: javascript, control-flow

So , i'm currently learning control flow and i have to build a program with else if conditions. The problem is that i keep getting this errors for else ifs : "Expected an identifier and saw else" and "Expected an assigment or function call and instead saw an expression". Here's the code:

```js
var moonPhase = 'full';

if (moonPhase === 'full') {
  console.log(Howwwlll!');}
      else if (moonPhase === 'mostly full'); {
        console.log('Arms and legs are getting hairier.');
      } else if (moonPhase === 'mostly new'); {
        console.log('Back on two feet');
      } else {
        console.log(Caution, unknown ');}
```

//So what did i do wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Protip: sometimes a syntax error is caused by a problem on the previous line.

Comment: `console.log(Howwwlll!');}` is missing the opening quote: `console.log('Howwwlll!');}`

Comment: ye forgot to put it there , but in my codecademy code , i got the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `;` in the if and else condition.  And also `console.log()` have a syntax error you are missing  start `'`  single quotes

```js
var moonPhase = 'full';

if (moonPhase === 'full') {
  console.log('Howwwlll!');
} else if (moonPhase === 'mostly full'){
  console.log('Arms and legs are getting hairier.');
} else if (moonPhase === 'mostly new'){
  console.log('Back on two feet');
} else {
  console.log('Caution, unknown');
}
```

Comment: Jesus the semicolons...Thank you so much!

Comment: @user8045551 always welcome .Don't forget [mark as a answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .Its helpful for future visitors